# Named Range insert by mouse

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

In Google Sheets, when I start to enter a formula and want to insert the reference to a cell, I just click on that cell and get the reference by row and column. However, if the cell is the part of Named Range it would be nice to get that Range Name on click. Is it possible?

In addition, I tried to click on the right panel with list of all Named Ranges, and once again I get ref by row and column (not by Name of the range).

How to get Name of the range with mouse clicking for referencing?

Comment: Since a cell could be part of multiple named ranges, there isn't a logical way to give a name of a range upon a cell click.

Comment: @NormalHuman Ok, but what with the list of defined ranges and I click at the name of the range?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible. You should consider to send comments to Google asking to include the features you are asking for.

Google Sheets users could send comments to Google from a Google spreadsheet by

1. Open a spreadsheet
2. Click on Help > Report a problem.
3. Fill and submit up the Google Feedback form.